# How to save related case accountNumber field on Task Using Process Builder

Tags: case, account, tasks, fields

I need to create a field in task where the value should be the task related case related Account Number.

[image]

[image]

I want task.whatid.account.accountnumber something like this

Comment: Why don't you go for apex trigger?

Comment: No other simple way to do?

Comment: You can use process builder also.

Comment: Process Builder doesnt works because reference goes till [task].whatId only. But I need somehing like this [task].whatid.Accountnumber

Comment: Do you need to start process builder on task object

Comment: Yes when a task record is created, assosciated accountnumber should be added

Comment: You would probably have to use process builder to call an autolaunched flow if process builder cannot reference the task.whatid but whatid is a lookup field so the account.id would need to be stored in there.

Answer (score 0):

Since the What field is a polymorphic lookup, it is not very flexible to fetch the data from the parent object.

If you are still willing to try a trigger, here is a sample code.

```
trigger updateCaseAccount on Task (before insert, before update) {
    List<Id> lstCaseIds = new List<Id>();

    for (Task task : trigger.new){ 
        if(task.WhatId != null){
            lstCaseIds.add(task.WhatId);
        }
    }

    Map<Id, Case> mapCases = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, Account.AccountNumber FROM Case WHERE Id =: lstCaseIds]);

    for (Task task : trigger.new){ 
        if(task.WhatId != null){
            task.Case_Account__c = mapCases.get(task.WhatId).Account.AccountNumber;
        }
    } 
}
```

I have created the field `Case_Account__c` as a text field, which will be populated with AccountNumber using the Account related to the Case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trigger.

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert, before update) {

    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Task t : trigger.new) { 
        if(t.WhatId != null && String.valueOf(t.WhatId).startWith('500')) {
            caseIds.add(t.WhatId);
        }
    }

    Map<Id, Case> caseMap = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.AccountNumber FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds]);

    for (Task t : trigger.new) { 
        if(t.WhatId != null) {
            t.Account_Number__c = caseMap.get(t.WhatId).Account.AccountNumber;
        }
    } 
}
```

You can also go for process builder with flows.